# Using OpenShift without some of its "features"

Tags: node.js, git, openshift, bitbucket, gulp

I enjoy the overall setup of OpenShift(the pricing isn't too shabby either ;) ), however, I've found myself put off a bit by the extra features that attempt to be my everything.

Specifically, OpenShift appears to want to be my Git repository, and my automated build system, however, I'd prefer to just use it as a host, and stick to my own Gulp.js build system in Cloud9 and a BitBucket repository.

So my question is, how would I go about hosting my project (it's in NodeJS) on OpenShift without using these features, which while I'm sure are great for some users, lack some of the flexibility I desire and already have with my current tools.

Also, if I simply am misunderstanding OpenShift's setup, please rectify my thinking.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The ability to use an external repo is something we're actually working on implementing. However, to my knowledge, it can't really be done today the way you're describing it. Although, someone else may be able to come up with a work around you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use all of the features that OpenShift provides, they are there for your convenience.  If you want to, you can think of the git repo as just a way to deploy your code, instead of being the end all be all of where you store your code, think of it as another "remote" repository that you push to just to deploy.  I also do that sometimes.  I keep all of my code on github or gitlab, or bitbucket in private repos, and only push to OpenShift when I want to deploy my project.  If you don't want to use the OpenShift build process for your project you might look into binary deployments (https://blog.openshift.com/using-openshift-without-git/), that way you can use your own build tools, bundle everything up into a tarball, and push it over to OpenShift to deploy.  You should be able to do all of this on Cloud9 since they provide you a shell and the ability to install the rhc gem (I am pretty sure you can).  if you need any further clarification let me know!

As a side note, you also might be able to rsync your code to the ~/app-root/repo directory, then issue an rhc app restart, but I haven't tried that with node.js code, it works with PHP and Ruby though.